# How to match a value in a child record with a parent record field value?

Tags: workflow, formula, picklist

I am trying to create a workflow that allows 2 cross object, custom, picklists to match each other. However, when I create a workflow, there is nowhere for me to add a formula. Not sure if there is a quick formula or way around this. Basically what I want it to do is:

Whenever an Account "Tier" is changed, I want the Contact "Tier" to match whatever the account tier is. Hopefully that makes sense. Any suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to update Contact Tier field equivalent to its link Account tier field value whenever it is updated? And do you have problem defining the workflow rule criteria or something else?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the issue I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to match the value from the parent (Account) you could create a formula in the contact object.

The formula would be something like
UPDATE: Updated for picklist field

```
   TEXT( Account.Tierfieldhere__c)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but because the Tier field is a picklist, I get the following error: Error: Field Tier__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Comment: @Michelle I have updated my answer to work with a picklist field